# How to sum last N rows in a column?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have the following setup:

[image]

I need to:

1. Sum last n values in column B (excluding empty values, in this example sum of the last 2 values would be 8).
2. Return corresponding value from column A on the last item summed in column B (for the last 2 items this would be 7 in B which corresponds to value P.
3. Return corresponding value from column A on the first item summed in column B (for the last 2 items this would be 1 in B which corresponds to K.

I would like this to be done without the use of VBA.

Answer (score 0):

This will return `K, P` & `1, 7`.

```
=INDEX(FILTER($A$1:$B$9,$B$1:$B$9<>""),SORT(SEQUENCE(2,1,SUM(--($B$1:$B$9<>"")),-1)),{1,2})
```

This will return `K, P`:

```
=INDEX(FILTER($A$1:$B$9,$B$1:$B$9<>""),SORT(SEQUENCE(2,1,SUM(--($B$1:$B$9<>"")),-1)))
```

This will return the sum of the figures (`8`):

```
=SUM(INDEX(FILTER($A$1:$B$9,$B$1:$B$9<>""),SORT(SEQUENCE(2,1,SUM(--($B$1:$B$9<>"")),-1)),2))
```

Further reading:  https://exceljet.net/formula/filter-on-first-or-last-n-values